# Html5 semantic elements - understanding

Tags: html

I've been programming  websites using html 4 for the past few years. Yesterday I've decide to move on and learn HTML5. Sadly, old browsers don't support HTML5, but I've found a js file"html5shiv" that will 'force' the browser to understand html5.

While learning HTML5 new semantics I've encountered few difficulties with understanding the difference between few elements.

When I looked at the `<figure>` tag, I read that:

"While the content of the `<figure>` element is related to the main flow, its position is independent of the main flow, and if removed it should not affect the flow of the document."

What is the meaning that it won't affect the flow of the document if removed?

Also, what's the difference between `<div>` and `<section>`? Moreover, what's the difference between `<article>` and `<section>` or `<div>`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: between what? 'flow' presumably means, that the layout of the site should not break if you remove a particular element

Comment: @Plato The seemingly nonsensical "between and" was the Markdown formatting engine's fault, not the OP's: anything that looks like an HTML tag is assumed to be one and passed through to the browser rather than escaped.

Answer (score 2):

`div` and `section` will be treated identically by browsers (because unknown elements are treated as `div`s.) The advantage of `section` is, it makes it explicit to someone reading source code, that this element represents a distinct set of information from other `section`s. And presumably in the future, search engines will prioritize information contained within a `section` over information contained in a `div`. In practice (as of 2013) a site will look and work the same if you replaced every `section` and `article` with a `div`. so the advantage is a) semantic readability and b) future proofing.

AFAIK the `article` tag denotes that its child elements (often `section`s) should be considered as parts of a whole.

quoting [w3schools: semantic elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp):

> The `<article>` element specifies independent, self-contained content.
>
> An article should make sense on its own and it should be possible to distribute it independently from the rest of the web site.
>
> Examples of where an  element can be used:
>
> Forum post
> Blog post
> News story
> Comment

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand the <article> tag. Let me understand something, let's say that I have a <section id="posts"> and inside that, each post will be an <article> and in each <article> I can use header,footer and sections?

Comment: @kfirba - Yes. HTML5Doctors provides a [flowchart](http://html5doctor.com/downloads/h5d-sectioning-flowchart.png) that seems to help understanding.